# OpenCV 2.4 inputText doesn't work correct

Tags: c++, opencv

Every time when I run the following program for writing text in an image it just writes five random chars instead of the input text. What can it be? Is this some memory leak or font error?
OpenCv 2.4
In python it works correctly but not in C++.

```
Mat img = imread("E:\\Projects\\MediaGUI\\lena.jpg");
putText(img, "Text For Testing..", Point(150, 150), CV_FONT_ITALIC, 3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
imwrite("E:\\Projects\\MediaGUI\\lenaProcessed.jpg", img);
img.addref();
img.release();
```

result img: http://postimg.org/image/kn4hoyjnh/

Comment: please carefully check the opencv libs you're linking again. do not mix debug and release libs (or use the wrong ones)

Comment: Thanks you berak, solved.They were linked with debug and few release libs I removed them

Comment: @AOquaish Adding "Thanks in Advance" is not "Correcting Spellings _[sic]_ and Grammar".